# Is there a way to set macOS' accent color on a per-app basis?

Tags: macos, color, sonoma, themes

After upgrading to macOS Sonoma, I can't see the yellow insertion point against the white background in Pages.

Is there a way to adjust or override the accent color of individual apps?

Answer (score 14):

Yes. The accent color and, by extension, the color of the insertion point can be adjusted on a per-app basis by assigning a value to the `AppleAccentColor` preferences key within the application's preferences domain.

The available accent colors are identified by an integer value as follows:

| Color | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Red | `0` |
| Orange | `1` |
| Yellow | `2` |
| Green | `3` |
| Blue | `4` |
| Violet | `5` |
| Magenta | `6` |

For Pages, the domain would be `com.apple.iWork.Pages`, so setting the accent color to the standard system blue would be done by using the `defaults` Terminal command below:

```shell
defaults write com.apple.iWork.Pages AppleAccentColor -integer 4
```

To revert the change use the `delete` option:

```shell
defaults delete com.apple.iWork.Pages AppleAccentColor
```

Comment: You can use `defaults write -app Pages` if you don't know what the domain name is.